# CORS issue with apache

Tags: php, angular, apache, .htaccess, centos

I'm having an issue making a request to my API server. (It was previously working), I'm not sure whats changed and things seem to make sense but I must be missing something.

I've tried looking at various articles and questions such as [CORS Issue - Angular / PHP / Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313776/cors-issue-angular-php-apache)
https://dev.to/effingkay/cors-preflighted-requests--options-method-3024
https://awesometoast.com/cors/

```
  post(platforms, message: string): any {
    console.log("Posting...");
    const data = {
      platforms,
      message
    };

    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/post`, data);
  }
```

Here's the php method that should be run:

```
    public function post()
    {
        return response(200);

    }
```

I'd just like to see a 200 response returned. But instread I'll get the following error:

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my.domain/api/customer-dash/post' from origin 'http://my.domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

.htaccess

```
#always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://my.domain"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

The tech stack is angular, php and apache on centos 7 server

Thanks

Comment: what version of angular are you using, particulary what version of httpClient?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]` – _all_ this does is (temporarily) set the response code to 200, it does not prevent this request from getting passed on to PHP. So this will “land” in your PHP system like any other request - and if you have not set anything up there to handle OPTIONS requests, the response code will probably get overwritten with an error code from there.

Comment: Angular cli verion 7.3.8. http module: 7.2.10

Comment: Hi @misorude, Its using laravel on the PHP backend. It will be set up to handle OPTIONS requests I would have thought, it worked previously as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an syntax error in my services.php file - issue resolved